# select all checkboxes with angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, selectall

I am trying to select all checkboxes with one single checkbox. But how to do that?

This is my HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />

<!-- userlist --> 
    <!--<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">-->
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Select</th>    
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="usersetting(user)" ng-model="user.select"></td>
        <td><tt>{{user.select}}</tt><br/></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

I create an extra checkbox to selecet and unselect all checkboxes.

JS:

```
.controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('users.json').then(function(usersResponse) {
      $scope.users = usersResponse.data;
    });

      $scope.checkAll = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.users, function (user) {
                user.select = true;
                });
            };  
 });
```

I tried this too, but none of them works for me :(

```
  $scope.checkAll = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function (user) {
            user.select = $scope.selectAll;
        });
    };
```

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914431/triggering-all-the-checkbox-event-while-selecting-checkall-in-angularjs/35914967#35914967

Comment: Is something happening when the `usersetting(user)` function is called? perhaps when you're checking all the checkboxes something in that function is refusing the request, and/or unchecking the box?

Comment: This question is like a duplicate of a duplicate.The link by @hadiJZ, should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missed the container divs with `ng-controller` and `ng-app` and `angular.module`.

`user.select = $scope.selectAll` is the correct variant.

https://jsfiddle.net/0vb4gapj/1/

Comment: neither works for me :/ But Thanks! :) Maybe there is an other issue :/ I've cpoied my Code in pasteBin... app.js and HTML pastebin.com/7eJu14nd pastebin.com/tq10Gtjb I just deleted the script for apiomat

Comment: @Paili 1. OnLoad references an unexistent function. 2. Your js code must be *after* `angular.js` in html (like app.js, for example).
Working code: http://pastebin.com/rMgmiRgW

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the checked boxes against each user to be checked when the top checkbox is checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll"/>    

<table class="table">
  <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Select</th>    
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="usersetting(user)" ng-model="user.select" ng-checked="selectAll"></td>
    <td><tt>{{user.select}}</tt><br/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/w7asr7hf/) you can use `ng-checked` with a variable on it like `user.checked` (or use the `user.select` as you want)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="usersetting(user)" ng-checked="user.checked" ng-model="user.select">
      </td>
      <td><tt>{{user.select}}</tt>
        <br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button ng-click="checkAll()">Check all</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('dummy', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Hello",
    select: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "World",
    select: 1
  }, ];
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
      user.checked = 1;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the following code

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.checked" data-ng-click="checkAll()" class="select-all" value="" />
```

JS

```
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
                angular.forEach($scope.users, function(item) {
                $scope.checkboxes.items[item._id] =      $scope.checkboxes.checked;
                $scope.selection.push(item._id);
            });
               }
```